# Importing from "django.(any module)" gives me this warning : could not be resolved from source

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, django-models

I have just created a Django project in a virtual environment and I'm getting this error or warning I'm not quite sure :

> (module) django Import "django.contrib" could not be resolved from
> source Pylance(reportMissingModuleSource)

in every line that has `import from django` .

I have searched for this problem and I have tried these so far :

1. editing Settings.JSON file in VScode by adding :

   ```
   "python.pythonPath": "C:/Users/abdur/dev/cfehome/django_project/Scripts/python.exe",
   ```

   Which is the python.exe location in my virtual environment
2. I have selected Python Interpreter to the one that is inside the virtual environment like this picture : [image]

   I have tried the other choice too but didn't work as well .

However when I run `python manage.py runserver` it works without giving me any errors but I'm trying to understand why I'm getting these warnings .

Answer (score 1):

this problem sometimes arises if you you are accessing your project from a virtual environment where django is not installed.if that's the case install django into your virtual env using the following command`pip install django` , it's simple but saves you the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've selected another interpreter from the one you're using for **your Django**. Try to follow these [steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69494651/14852553), I've described in similar question. Whish you good luck!