# How to resolve 'Import "django.contrib" could not be resolved from source' in VS Code?

Tags: python-3.x, django, visual-studio-code

This error suddenly came up when I created a new Django project. I used pip to install all the packages in the virtual environment.

[image]

Comment: Could you please mark one of the answers as correct one if of course any of those were able to solve your problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 58):

I had exactly the same problem and there are several solutions out there, but only [@Neha's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16250361/neha) answer has brought me to the point. The problem here is really simple. VS Code uses your **"main" Python interpreter**, whereas you should use the one in your virtual environment for Django.

In other words, I have my main Python installation here:
`c:\users\yourName\appdata\local\programs\python\python39`.

And my VS Code has pointed to exactly this interpreter. But my Django was installed in this path:
`c:\users\yourName\source\vscode-repos\basic-app\backend-service\venvs\lib\site-packages`.

In order to solve it click on the
**[VS Code bar with Python Interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOqr1.png)**, you will then see a pop-up window. Choose **[+ Enter interpreter path...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ogm6P.png)** then **[Find...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDCzm.png)**. It will open **File Explorer** for you. Go to your **virtual environment folder**, where you have your Django installed (in my case it the **vscode-repos\basic-app\backend-service\venvs** folder), inside of it go to the `Scripts` folder and pick **python.exe**, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4l2Um.png). And you are good to go!

Comment: This is an excellent answer!

Comment: I am getting the same problem using VS2022 Professional.  Presumably the cause is the same, but I cannot find how to tell VS2022 which path to use to find the correct version of the interpreter.

Comment: amazing answerr

Answer (score 14):

Select the Python interpreter in which you have created the virtual environment. I had the same error and this solution worked.

Below is a screenshot that you can refer to.

[image]

Comment: in my case it was the same, I only had to select the right python intepreter by cmd+shift+p and run the command Python: Select Interpreter and then select the recommended interpreter...

hope it helps LP

Answer (score 8):

Actually all of the answers were right , but what worked for me is:

1. Type `pip show Django` in vsc terminal
2. Go to the path of intallation mentioned there
3. It will be inside "lib" by default..go back to scripts
4. Inside the scripts , there will be python .exe app
5. Choose this as your interpreter (as per above answers)

Comment: nice tip. I didn't need to go into scripts, just pointed at the (in my case) `.../python/3.9.4` directory of the installation

Comment: you could have said "search Python: select interpreter" for linux... I was scrolling forever in the command pallette

Answer (score 5):

If you are using VScode, click the python version on the bottom left corner and select the venv where you have installed the packages.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who can't see the virtual environment then click on the python version below right corner of vscode,click on Enter Interpretor Path,click find,chose the folder that you are working,click on virtual environment name ,then click bin and select python version and the warning will be gone.

Comment: Yes this is the only one that I could get to work on WSL and Windows

Answer (score 1):

In my case (on **MacOS**) the problem was caused by **creating venv using default arguments**.

I don't have `Scripts` directory, but I've got `bin` inside. The `python3 -m venv my_venv` command was creating **symlinks** to `python` and `python3` executables which was confusing for the VSCode. After removing and creating again the venv with below command everything started to work

```
python3 -m venv --upgrade-deps --copies my_venv
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Python(Extentions) below your screen [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EIoE.png) then select interpreter tab will pop up, then select C:\Python39\python.exe [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KX1AT.png).Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to install django within my virtualenv. All other settings were correct in Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

I had also face same problem but simple solution is configure your main python interpreter path from this option +Enter interpreter path..

which common path can be like this either may be different :

C:\Users\YOURNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe

After selecting that path, Here your error get solved and it will removed orange wavy underlines.

- For windows OS

Answer (score 0):

You could as well add:

```
# pylint: disable=import-error
```

to the top of your file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VScode, run:
`cnrl+shift+p`
then select Python: Select Interpreter
finally, select your current virtual environment directory from your project.
I hope it should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MacBook, follow the below steps:

**Step 1:** Open the search console by hitting command+shift+p

**Step 2:** Search for - Python: Select Interpreter (Refer to screenshot)
[image]

**Step 3:** Select the venv path from the dropdown
[image]

This should fix the error you are seeing.