# Setting Up Django. Stuck on Models. Going through the tutorial. Not Sure what to do

Tags: django, django-models

I am doing the tutorial on django for an assignment. I am doing it step by step. I got an issue when I copied and pasted the suggested code and am unable to do the last few steps on models. Please let me know how to move forward. It is really frustrating when the guide I am following is unable to offer assistance.[image of VScode code editor for models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJ29t.png)

Comment: Have you installed Django? Does your project run? Is this just an issue with configuring your IDE?

Comment: it ran and opened the initial website, the next set of instructions about models would not work because these first few lines arent finding their references or something

Comment: Are you using virtual environment?

Comment: I think they are just warning VS code cannot resolve the imports

Comment: See if this answer can help you get vscode set up for your virtual environment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67586182/how-to-resolve-import-django-contrib-could-not-be-resolved-from-source-in-vs